# downloading big size(In MB) .txt files using NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm downloading .txt files using NSURLConnection. Small size (in KB's) files are downloading perfectly but when i downloading big size(In MB) file, it always downloaded with corrupt data.
Sometimes big size .txt files are downloaded. But when i fetch those .txt file programmatically, it shows null content in it.
Please help.....
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting some code would go a long way toward getting some better help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) wrapper classes for HTTP request. They make the download of big sized files easy as they allow to download the files directly to the file system. I am currently using these wrapper classes on a project and I can assure you that they make your life a lot easier.